# objective c implicit conversion loses integer precision 'NSUInteger'

Tags: ios, objective-c, compiler-errors, warnings

Following a tutorial on treehouse, I'm see this popular Object-C warning message in XCode.

My button function

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
    NSUInteger index = arc4random_uniform(predictionArray.count);
    self.predictionLabel.text = [predictionArray objectAtIndex:index];
}
```

I see it on the NSUInteger line, I've few a few of the similar stackoverflows and they seem to  talk about 32bit vs 64bit numbers and type casting, but not sure how to do that here?

My predictionArray

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    predictionArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                   @"It is certain", @"It is decidely so", @"All signs say YES", @"The stars are not aligned",
                   @"My reply is no",
                   @"It is doubtful",
                   @"Better not tell you now",
                   @"Concentrate and ask again",
                   @"Unable to answer now", nil];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You can safely suppress the warning with a cast.

```
NSUInteger index = arc4random_uniform((uint32_t) predictionArray.count);
```

It's not always *safe* to suppress warnings, so don't go casting things to get rid of the warnings until you figure out whether the operation is safe.

What's going on here is that `NSUInteger` is, on your platform, a typedef for a 64-bit integer type.  It's not *always* 64 bits, just on some platforms.  The compiler is warning you that some of those bits are getting thrown away.  If you know that these bits are unimportant, you can just use a cast.

In this case, the result is that `index` will always be under 2<sup>32</sup>-1.  If it's even remotely possible for `predictionArray` to contain 2<sup>32</sup> or more elements, then your program has an error and you'll have to construct a 64-bit version of `arc4random_uniform()`.  You can ensure this with the following code:

```
assert(predictionArray.count <= (uint32_t) -1);
```

Comment: Hmm, I just tried this, but still the same warning. So what am I casting NSUInteger as? What does `(NSUInteger)` mean. Or maybe more importantly, what is it warning me about?

Comment: Thanks! Still trying to understand this, so `NSUInteger` is always a 32 bit int? I tried to cast it as a 64 bit and got the same error. That bit stuff is new to me, never had to run into it before

Comment: Deitrich, I don't want to edit your answer and step on toes, but I'd maybe expand it to explain *why* the cast is necessary.

@LeonGaban `arc4random_uniform()` takes in, and returns, a `uint32_t`, an unsigned integer that is always 32 bits, regardless of target architecture. However, `predictionArray.count` returns an `NSUInteger`, which is `typedef`d differently for 32-bit and 64-bit systems; it's 32 bits on a 32-bit system, and 64-bits on a 64-bit system. If you're running on a 64-bit system, passing in a 64-bit `NSUInteger` will cause the compiler to complain that you're throwing away bits.

Comment: @ItaiFerber: There is nothing that annoys me more on Stack Overflow than responding to requests like yours... you obviously know the answer.  You can (1) put your knowledge in a comment, (2) edit it into my answer, (3) create your own answer.  In the future refrain from choosing option (4), ask someone else to explain something that you know on your behalf.  I am not your secretary.

Comment: That wasn't my intent. You'd already gotten an upvote and Leon marked your answer as correct — just leaving a comment (1) would leave your answer as the canonical one, even if it was incomplete and my comment was valid. (2) Some people take extreme offense at having their answers forcibly edited, and I have no intention of offending anyone. (3) If your answer was already marked as correct, from experience, even if I'd put up a more complete answer, the asker would likely ignore it anyway. (4) So I chose to politely recommend you expand your answer. That's all.

Answer (score 11):

As per my comment, `arc4random_uniform()` takes in, and returns, a `u_int32_t`, an unsigned integer that is always 32 bits, regardless of target architecture. However, `predictionArray.count` returns an `NSUInteger`, which is `typedef`d differently for 32-bit and 64-bit systems; it's 32 bits (`unsigned int`) on a 32-bit system, and 64-bits (`unsigned long`) on a 64-bit system. If you're running on a 64-bit system, passing in a 64-bit `NSUInteger` to a function expecting a 32-bit integer will cause the compiler to complain that you're throwing away bits.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, so if I send a 32 bit number into a 64 bit function/method does that slow down the program? Or is it just saying I could be more efficient. Is there a 64bit version of `arc4random_uniform()`? Or should I just use `u_int32_t` a lot?

Comment: @LeonGaban An unnoticeable amount, if at all. Your 32-bit number has to get extended to become 64-bits; if it's unsigned, then it will automatically become extended with 0s, and if it's signed and negative, it will get extended with 1s. It's not really an issue. However, if you try to pass in a 64-bit number into a 32-bit function, parts of your number can get thrown out (the function only gets the lower 32 bits), and the compiler complains (which is why you have to assure it that you know what you're doing with a cast).

Comment: @LeonGaban Unfortunately, there's no 64-bit version of the `arc4random*` functions, but keep casting into them and you'll be alright. I recommend against using `u_int32_t` everywhere because it is, by definition, 32-bits. `NSUInteger` has the advantage of being `typedef`d for you by Apple to match the target platform, so you can always use it and know that you're doing things efficiently (you don't want to arbitrarily limit the size of your data unless it makes sense and is necessary).